# Given a melpa/elpa package, find other elpa/melpa libraries that depend on it

Tags: package-repositories

I am trying to use [oauth2.el](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/oauth2.html) for some local shenanigans and would like to see how others are using it. Is there a way I can query elpa/melpa for dependencies to this (or any other package)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about querying the package archive directly, but you can do something along the lines of:

```lisp
(let ((needle 'oauth2)
      (resolve-deps-recursively t)
      curr-deps
      all-rdeps)
  (dolist (curr package-archive-contents all-rdeps)
    ;; (car curr) => pkg
    ;; (cadr curr) => pkg-desc
    (setq curr-deps (if resolve-deps-recursively
                        (package--dependencies (car curr))
                      (mapcar #'car (package-desc-reqs (cadr curr)))))
    (when (memq needle curr-deps)
      (push (car curr) all-rdeps))))
```

This will find all reverse dependencies of `needle`.  If `resolve-deps-recursively` is non-nil, it will, as the name suggests, resolve dependencies recursively.  In other words, if `pkg1` depends on `pkg2` which depends  on [...] which depends on `pkgn` which depends on `needle`, `pkg1` will appear in the result.

Given my `package-archive-contents`, I get the following results for `'oauth2`:

```lisp
;; with recursive dependency resolution
'(flim google-contacts mu-cite oauth2-request org-onenote semi slack smudge wanderlust)

;; without recursive dependency resolution
'(flim google-contacts oauth2-request org-onenote slack smudge)
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks!